# Substracting the last row of each group in a groupby dataframe from each row in the same group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset with cases and events belonging to these cases. I want to substract the first datetime of the first event from each of the events in that case to get time elapsed since beginning of the case.

I do:

```
grouped = data.groupby("case_id")
data["T_elapsed"] = grouped["event_id"].transform(lambda x: x-x.iloc[0])
```

It works, but it is terribly slow for a bigger dataset. Are there any less computationally expensive alternatives to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) or 
[`last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) for `Series` with subtracting column `data['event_id']`:

```
grouped = data.groupby("case_id")
data["T_elapsed"] = data['event_id'] - grouped["event_id"].transform('first')
```

---

```
grouped = data.groupby("case_id")
data["T_elapsed"] = data['event_id'] - grouped["event_id"].transform('last')
```

Comment: Thank you, that is extremely more efficient!